# Data in Mysql Table only store one record

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql data base in which i am adding data in mysql data base but problem is that it only stores only one record not more than that.

my table structure is

```
    <?php
    $con =  mysql_connect("example.com","name","password");

    if (!$con)
     {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     mysql_select_db("surveyipad", $con);

     $response_id=$_POST['response_id'];

     $participant_id=$_POST['participant_id'];


     $question_id=$_POST['question_id'];



     $answer_text=$_POST['answer_text'];


     $answer_option=$_POST['answer_option'];


     $query=("INSERT INTO survey_question_responses (response_id,participant_id,question_id,answer_text,answer_option)

      VALUES ('', '$participant_id','$question_id','$answer_text','$answer_option')");

       mysql_query($query,$con);
       printf("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());

     echo($response_id)
   ?>
```

response id is primary key in table and also set to auto increment

Comment: Could you change "mysql_query($query,$con)" to "mysql_query($query,$con) or die(mysql_error())" and tell us what error you see?

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain).

Comment: Also, as stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Comment: there is no any error in code i thins if it error then how it is inserting one record

Comment: What value does response_id have in your first row?

Comment: it inserts only one record starting from 0 primary key

Comment: @user1619187 do u added the auto increment to the primary key if any???

Comment: yes i have added autoincremetn to primary key

Comment: response id is primary key  and has value 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$query=("INSERT INTO survey_question_responses (participant_id,question_id,answer_text,answer_option)

      VALUES ('$participant_id','$question_id','$answer_text','$answer_option')");
```

Comment: again same how will be response_id inserted

Comment: there is also respone_id in table how to insert that also or that will be automatically inserted

Comment: @user1619187  `response_id` is auto_increment field. It will update automatically with inserting new row. Try to check   
 `mysql_error($con)` after mysql_query.

Comment: so why it is only inserting one record  and may wirte mysql_error($con) a

Answer (score 0):

As you made the id field auto incremented don't insert it vie your INSERT query .

Write the query as

```
INSERT INTO survey_question_responses (participant_id, question_id, answer_text, answer_option)
VALUES ('$participant_id', '$question_id', '$answer_text', '$answer_option')
```

You should also explain or send the structure of your table.